# The best my.cnf for my AWS server

Tags: mysql, aws, centos

I have an amazon server , my mysql is very slow , i dont know what is the best configration for my server , i need to big caching system for improving my website speeds, it's my config  :
 **my.conf** :

```
[mysqld]
log="/var/log/mysqld.log"
local-infile=0
default-storage-engine=myisam
query_cache_limit=2M
query_cache_size=1024M
query_cache_type=1
max_user_connections=250
max_connections=1000
thread_cache_size=128
table_cache=1024M
key_buffer=2G
open_files_limit=51780
table_definition_cache=20000
join_buffer_size=64M
long_query_time=2
log-slow-queries="/var/lib/mysql/slow.log"
max_heap_table_size=256M
tmp_table_size=256M
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
max_allowed_packet=268435456
```

**Cpu details :**

```
Total processors: 8  
2800.060 MHz  (for each processor)
25600 KB Cache  (for each processor)
```

**Ram details(GB)**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            14         14          0          0          1          6
-/+ buffers/cache:          6          8
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You might have a perfectly configured system which would still be slow if you had a heavy load. What version of MySQL are you running? What's your traffic like?

I'm worried about this "default-storage-engine=myisam" - what storage engine do your tables use? If your app is update heavy and all of your tables use MyISAM, then you could be experiencing locking issues - MyISAM is good for read-heavy/write-light types of load.

Take a look at the Performance Schema (P_S) - it tells you where your system is spending its time - you can go after the low-hanging fruit that way. Don't just go blindly changing my.cnf parameters in the hope that something "good" is going to happen.

Your bottleneck could be I/O? What's your configuration in that area? Are you coming close to any limits in your Amazon package?

[EDIT in response to OP's question]

Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html). Also, you could use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to install it. Workbench is a great (Open Source) tool anyway so there's no reason not to use it. The only problem is that the P_S only came into existence for 5.5 - so it's functionality is limited compared to the 5.6 releases. If you can upgrade, I would.

Comment: I'm using INODB in my tables , My mysql version is 5.5.37 , how can i check performance schema?